# Pytest in Flask test get_single_object by passing an id

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, pytest

I'm writing tests for my flask api and using Python(3.7). I have a view function to get a single object by passing its id in the route, now I want to write unit test for this view.

Here's what I have done so far:

From `view function:`

```
@api.route("/book/<int:id>", methods=["GET", "PUT", "DELETE"])
def single_book(id):
    conn = db_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    book = {}
    if request.method == "GET":
        try:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE id=?", (id,))
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            for r in rows:
                book = r
            book = {
                "id": book[0],
                "author": book[1],
                "title": book[2],
                "shortDescription": book[3],
                "thumbnailUrl": book[4],
                "status": book[5],
                "pageCount": book[6],

            }
            conn.close()
        except Error as e:
            return 'SQL Error'
        print(book)
        if book is not None:
            return jsonify(book), 200
        else:
            return "Something wrong", 404
```

**From `testing file:`**

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    db_fd, app.config['DATABASE'] = tempfile.mkstemp()

    with app.test_client() as client:
        with app.app_context():
            create_table()
            yield client
    os.close(db_fd)
    os.unlink(app.config['DATABASE'])
    # return app.test_client()

def api_single_book(client, book_id):
    return client.get('/api/book/{}'.format(book_id), follow_redirects=True)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('id', [1])
def test_single_book(client, id):
    resp = api_single_book(client, id)
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```

Now, if I run the `pytest` command all other tests are passed only this one failed with the following error:

> **E               KeyError: 0**

and it's pointing to this line:

**>    "id": book[0],**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if the query returns `None`? And why are you redefining `book` in the loop, then again?  It will only have the last in the loop.  I think you want to redefine your query or loop, but I'll use what you have.

Try this:

```
for r in rows:
    print(r) # to see what you have
    book = {
        "id": r[0],
        "author": r[1],
        "title": r[2],
        "shortDescription": r[3],
        "thumbnailUrl": r[4],
        "status": r[5],
        "pageCount": r[6],
    }
```